# how to make browser display chinese characters properly

Tags: locale

I am using raspberry pi 3.

I am using the default browser for testing. I have added a new language under preferences and set to Chinese(China).

When I visit a Django website that has localization turned on, the chinese characters show up as weird boxes.

How do I get the chinese characters to show up?

Answer (score 2):

I then typed the following command

`sudo apt-get install ttf-wqy-microhei`

The content of the webpage now correctly shows the chinese language